# qTest | Jenkinsfile Pipeline Integration

Tags: jenkins, junit, jenkins-pipeline, qtest

I have integrated qTest with Jenkinsfile pipeline after following below link.
https://www.qasymphony.com/video-training/qtest/project-admin/how-to-integrate-qtest-jenkins-pipeline-projects/

After integration with my pipeline, I am observing below errors.

```
com.qasymphony.ci.plugin.exception.SaveSettingException: CI Integration Setting is disabled.
    at com.qasymphony.ci.plugin.ConfigService.saveConfiguration(ConfigService.java:317)
    at com.qasymphony.ci.plugin.action.SubmitJUnitStep$SubmitJUnitStepExecution.loadPipelineConfiguration(SubmitJUnitStep.java:479)
    at com.qasymphony.ci.plugin.action.SubmitJUnitStep$SubmitJUnitStepExecution.run(SubmitJUnitStep.java:302)
Caused: java.lang.Exception
    at com.qasymphony.ci.plugin.action.SubmitJUnitStep$SubmitJUnitStepExecution.run(SubmitJUnitStep.java:305)
    at com.qasymphony.ci.plugin.action.SubmitJUnitStep$SubmitJUnitStepExecution.run(SubmitJUnitStep.java:240)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1$1.call(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:50)
    at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:290)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1.run(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Jenkinsfile pipeline script

```
stage('Publish_qTest'){
        steps{
        submitJUnitTestResultsToqTest([apiKey: 'f8810j2w-d123-1110-e22a-2c5ae5b123cd', containerID: 380012, containerType: 'release', createTestCaseForEachJUnitTestClass: true, createTestCaseForEachJUnitTestMethod: false, overwriteExistingTestSteps: true, parseTestResultsFromTestingTools: true, parseTestResultsPattern: './*.xml', projectID: 12345, qtestURL: 'https://orguk.qtestnet.com/', submitToAReleaseAsSettingFromQtest: true, submitToExistingContainer: false, utilizeTestResultsFromCITool: false])
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should go to settings -> Automation settings and make sure you have enabled CI Tool Integration on your Qtest instance.

It basically needs to be enabled before it allow you to report.

Answer (score 1):

To Integrate Jenkins with Qtest please follow the below steps.

1. Login to qtest  or create a trial account.
2. Create a simple project and add some releases etc.
3. Goto Settings menu on the right corner and click automation settings and perform the following.
   a) Enable automation integration status
   b) Add mappings for passed and failed test cases.
   c) Activate CI tool Integration
   d) Select a module (project name) from dropped down. where all test cases will be saved.